# how to move a cordova project from intel xdk to visual studio

Tags: visual-studio, cordova, visual-studio-2015, intel-xdk

I'm trying to move a project created in Intel XDK to Visual Studio 2015.
I used the file > new > project from existing code ... option to create a new project in VS from the Intel XDK project.

I commented out the script line for the cordova.js file. because i read somewhere that VS creates and inserts for you.

when i go to build i get:

`cordova-build error BLD105: The Cordova build did not recognize your working directory as a Corvova-based project. This is often because the "www" directory is not at the root of your project`

I have a www directory in the project folder.

I determine that the cause was i didn't have a `config.xml` file in the root directory. it seems the XDK application creates the `config.xml` when it calls Cordova to do a build.

I have the following questions:

1. What is the best way to get a `config.xml` file?
2. Is there any other gotchas from moving the project?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest way is to make a new Cordova project, open config.xml by viewing the code instead of in the designer, select all & copying it to your clipboard. Then, re-open your XDK project, add a new item, call it config.xml and drop your clipboard contents into it.

You may need to re-configure a bunch of settings to get parity with what Intel does, but this should unblock the build.

(Disclosure: I work on the Tools for Apache Cordova in Visual Studio at Microsoft. And thanks for using our tools!)